# Cannot execute xsd.exe on xslt.xsd

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xslt, xsd.exe

Visual Studio provides a schema definition for XSLT under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\xslt.xsd".

However, when trying to generate C# classes based on the .xsd

```
xsd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\xslt.xsd" /classes
```

the tool only generates an error message saying

> Error: Error generating classes for schema 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10_0\Xml\Schemas\xslt'.
>
> - Group 'char-instructions' from targetNamespace='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' has invalid
>     definition: Circular group reference.

What steps or modifications are necessary to run the command successfully? Or, has this been done before, and are the results available on the web?

(Yes, I know, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139523/21336) suggests writing my own classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by incrementally editing the xsd file and running xsd.exe on the modified files. See [my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/dealing-with-circular-group-reference-errors-in-xsd-exe/) for details how to proceed.